# Why does StrToInt('X5') returns 5 in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Why does StrToInt('X5') returns 5 in Delphi?  Is X some scientific notation or something like it?  Are there some other chars which will be converted to Integer as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not knowing Delphi, I'd wager that the "X" causes the function to assume the value is hexidecimal.  Since 0x5 == 5, it appears to be working.  Try X10 and see if you get back 16.

Answer (score 11):

In Delphi, hexadecimal values are marked with $ prefix:

```
a := $10;  // => a = 16
```

But since in some other languages (e.g. C) X is used for marking hexadecimal values, StrToInt function supports both $ and X prefixes, so both of the codes below return 16:

```
a := StrToInt('x10'); // => a = 16

a := StrToInt('$10'); // => a = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hex notation. Try XF to see it return 15.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation.

The X indicates that the number that follows is hexadecimal (0-9 + A-F).